# HTML Sidebar List

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I've been able able to put some code together that creates an HTML list which details the location markers plotted in my map.

At the moment the title of the HTML list is shown as 'undefined'. I've tried changing the 'div' name and 'element' which to me seemed to be the logical place, but I was obviously wrong, because I just can't get it to change.

Then when I hover over the list items, the mouse icon shown suggests it's a text field rather than a link and no matter what I try to change I just can't get it to work.

Finally when I click on the HTML list item the map correctly pans and centres on the appropriate marker but I can't get the InfoWindow to open. I've tried what I feel are all the permuatations of the code to try resolve this but nothing works.

**EDIT - CODE INSERTED**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Map My Finds - All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mylocations.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>


        <div id="map"></div> 
        <div id="locationslist"></div> 

        <body onload="showLocations()"> 

            <script type="text/javascript"> 

                var map; 
                var gmarkers = new Array();
                var locationslist;

                function showLocations() { 
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
                zoom:6, 
                mapTypeId: 'terrain' 
                }); 
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 

                // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
                downloadUrl("loadmylocations.php", function(data) { 
                var xml = data.responseXML; 
                gmarkers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
                for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) { 
                var locationname = gmarkers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
                var address = gmarkers[i].getAttribute("address"); 
                var locationid = gmarkers[i].getAttribute("locationid"); 
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
                parseFloat(gmarkers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
                parseFloat(gmarkers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon"))); 
                var html = "<b>" + locationname + "</b> <br/>" + address; 
                bounds.extend(point);  
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                map: map, 
                position: point, 
                locationid: locationid 
                }); 
                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);  
                locationslist += "<div onclick=scrollToMarker(" + i + ")>"+locationname+"</div>"; 
                }        
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); 
                map.fitBounds(bounds);  
                //display company data in html 
                document.getElementById("locationslist").innerHTML = locationslist; 
                });  
                } 

                function scrollToMarker(index) {  
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
                parseFloat(gmarkers[index].getAttribute("osgb36lat")),  
                parseFloat(gmarkers[index].getAttribute("osgb36lon")) 
                ); 
                map.panTo(point);  
                } 

                function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) { 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
                infoWindow.setContent(html); 
                infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
                }); 
                } 

                function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
                var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
                new XMLHttpRequest; 

                request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                if (request.readyState == 4) { 
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
                callback(request, request.status); 
                } 
                }; 

                request.open('GET', url, true); 
                request.send(null); 
                } 
                function doNothing(){ 
                } 

                </script> 
                </head>    
                </body> 
            </html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that prints the `undefined` message?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here.  Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/multi-question-questions-how-best-to-handle-them for various reasons why you might not want to do that.

Comment: I realise this is probably a coincidence, but I grew up a couple of streets away from your test location 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I hover over the list items, the mouse icon shown suggests it's a
>   text field rather than a link

To fix this, add the following to your css

```
div#locationslist div{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

By the way, @Trott is right... this question should be split into three questions.

Comment: Hi, firstly, apologies to all if I caused offence by asking to many questions in one post, I'll keep them to one question in future. Secondly, sincere thanks for replying to my post. In terms of the code that prints the 'undefined' message, I'm afraid I'm not even sure where this. As I said earlier I've put together the code from other posts I've read and from some tuition, so perhaps my understanding isn't as good as it should be. I've added the code I'm using to my original post. Many thanks for helping me on this. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: No offense, Chris!  It's just you are more likely to get good responses if there is one question per post.  Thanks for posting the code.  I will have another look.

Comment: Jason, sincere thanks for your help and your kind words. Regards. Chris

Comment: Many thanks for the help with the mouse pointer it works great. Kind regards